# iPad 3rd generation can not display retina image

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I have develop one universal app. I have four type images

- iphone - simple.png
- iphone retina - simple@2x.png
- ipad -   simple@3x.png
- ipad retina - simple@3x@2x.png

When i try to run the application, it works fine into ipad (non retina) but it gives black screen (no images) into ipad retina.

Here, put code of function which give me related name for iphone & ipad.

```
#define SHImageString(str, ext) ({ UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", (str), (ext)]) : ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@3x.%@", (str), (ext)]); })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really confusing naming scheme if you ask me...

Comment: Can you tell me why it can't display retina images.

Comment: try different names, leave out the "@3" maybe that's what's confusing the selection of the right image file.

Comment: Before it, i have used simple_ipad.png and simple_ipad@2x.png, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

- iphone-simple.png
- iphone retina - simple@2x.png
- ipad - simple_iPad.png
- ipad retina - simple_iPad@2x.png

In your code (or XIB) you only use the files without the `@2x`. If the app is run on a retina display it will automatically use the `@2x` version. I've used this many many time, works perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me check